# Pegar o value de um select option do html e colocar na query.

Tags: php, html

Estou com uma dúvida enorme, seria o seguinte;

Preciso pegar o value do Select Option que está no form HTML e jogar na query SQL que está no mesmo aquivo .PHP, segue ex:

```
    <select name="origem" id="origem">
  <option>-- Selecione a Origem --</option>
  <?php
                $Q_secc = "SELECT codigo,descricao FROM seccionamentos ORDER BY descricao";
                $R_secc = mysql_query($Q_secc,$conexao);
                while ($l_secc = mysql_fetch_array($R_secc)){
                ?>
  <option value="<?=$l_secc['codigo']?>">
  <?=utf8_encode($l_secc['descricao']);?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

este já está sendo alimentado pelo select acima.
e abaixo é outro select option, só que este teria que ser alimentado pelo value selecionado acima.

```
<select name="horario" id="horario">
  <option>-- Selecione a Horário --</option>
  <?php
                $Q_horario = "SELECT H.codigo, H.horario
                           FROM tarifas T
                           INNER JOIN linhas L ON L.codigo = T.linha
                           INNER JOIN horarios H ON H.linha = L.codigo
                           WHERE T.origem = valor do 1º combo
                           AND T.destino= 170
                           AND H.sentido = 'I'
                           AND ((MID(H.frequencia, 1, 1) = 'S') AND 
                           (MID(H.frequencia1002, 1, 1) = 'S'))
                           ORDER BY H.horario
                ";
                $R_secc = mysql_query($Q_horario,$conexao);
                while ($l_secc = mysql_fetch_array($R_secc)){
                ?>
  <option value="<?=$l_secc['codigo']?>">
  <?=utf8_encode($l_secc['horario'])?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Gostaria que no where ficasse o value do 1º combobox origem.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você vai precisar fazer uma requisição assíncrona onde você chamará uma página `php` apenas para trazer as opções do segundo `select`, você consegue algo de `ajax`, `javascript`? Segue um link com um exemplo que pode te ajudar: https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: Não resolveria, pq tenho que fazer no mesmo formulário!

Comment: Não resolveria, pq tenho que fazer essa chamada na combo no mesmo formulário.

Comment: Para o usuário será no mesmo formulário, sugiro ler sobre ajax.

Comment: Tem como fazer isso não. Como é que o PHP vai saber qual option foi selecionado? Só usando Ajax ou fazendo reload na página.